# jquery pathname and syntax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pathname

In order to load a page with ajax I have the following in my script file:

```
$(".ajaxed").live("click", function(event) {
    var post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname.substring(1);
    alert(post_slug);
    $.address.crawlable(true).value(post_slug);
    $("#board").load("ajax/",{slug:post_slug});
    return false;
});
```

When the user clicks on an anchor linking to http://www.website.com/link1 the post_slug alert is link1. But when I use this in IE8 the post_slug alert is ink1 instead of link1. What am I doing wrong ?

I guess it's .substring(1) but what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$(this)[0].pathname.replace("/", "");
```

Tested on IE7, Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/vB2Fu/3/

You can make the replace bit more careful by using regex to replace only the starting slash

```
$(this)[0].pathname.replace(/^\//, "");
```

**Update:**

For nested slugs, I changed it a bit:

```
$(this)[0].pathname.substring($(this)[0].pathname.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(/^\//, "");
```

Demo (tested on IE7, Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/vB2Fu/5/

Comment: what if the slug is nested `/category/link1`?

Comment: I have http://site.com/myblog/category/link1 and it doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

substring(1) means to start at the 2nd character.  substring(from,to).  So IE is not returning the initial "/".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that IE returns a different value for `pathname` (without the leading `/`).

You can either test for it and use/omit `substring` accordingly or get the whole URL and use `split`

Answer (score 0):

could test for it

```
if ($(this)[0].pathname.substring(0, 1) === "/") {
    post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname.substring(1);
} else {
    post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname; // ie8 oddness
}
```